# I am try to create BottomNavigationView with fragment and I want to use fragment in main layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

It can build and run successfully but in virtual device has stopped.
this is the code of my main layout in fragment:

```
public class BlankFragment14 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                              Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment14, container, false);

    }


        @Override
        public void onCreate( @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            BottomNavigationView bottomNav = getView( ).findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
            BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = null;
            bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

            getFragmentManager( ).beginTransaction( ).replace(R.id.fragment_container1, new ProfileFragment( )).commit( );

            navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener( ) {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected( @NonNull MenuItem menuItem ) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId( )) {
                        case R.id.nav_profile1:
                            selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment( );
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_appointment1:
                            selectedFragment = new AppointmentFragment( );
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_patientdata1:
                            selectedFragment = new PatientdataFragment( );
                            break;
                    }
                    getFragmentManager( ).beginTransaction( ).replace(R.id.fragment_container1, selectedFragment).commit( );

                    return true;
                }
            };


        }


    }
```

I don't know that It  can be possible to work ? or I must use activity to be a main layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use Navigation component to implement BottomNavigationView. Your MainActivity must have NavHostFragment, that can display other fragment destinations. In MainActivity's onCreate
setup NavController as shown below:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
   //NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
}
```